# May I drive an Indian-registered car in Nepal?

Tags: legal, india, driving, automobiles, nepal

My car is registered in India. I Plan to visit Nepal for 10 days. Am I allowed to bring and drive my car there, or would I need to re-register it in Nepal?

Answer (score 2):

You are allowed to bring your own car, after paying a small amount of fees

Documents required entering Nepal with own vehicle

- Registration Certificate of vehicle
- Driving license
- Customs permit (called Bhansar in Nepali)
- Vehicle Permit (called yaatayaat anumati in Nepali)

More details and fees at: https://www.touristhelpline.com/documents-required-for-entering-nepal-with-own-car-bike/